# Is it okay for a duck/splay footed individual to rock climb?

Tags: rock-climbing, health

If an individual walks with a pronounced duck-footed (splayed) gait, and is actively trying to correct this, is there any harm for the individual to begin rock climbing. I feel like a lot of edging during rock climbing puts your feet in a pretty extreme toe-out position and therefore may exacerbate the issue.

Comment: so edge toe-in?

Comment: @endolith that seems pretty extreme, especially if climbing toe out doesn't hurt the effort to stop walking toe out.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.ifsc-climbing.org/index.php/world-competition/paraclimbing

People with some pretty extreme physical impairments find ways to rock climb and also accomplish their other rehabilitation goals.  If I were you / this person I would ask whatever physiotherapist is guiding them in their rehab but unless specifically contraindicated, the general strength flexibility and fitness demanded and encouraged by climbing is likely greater benefit than harm.

Comment: mmcc, I very much appreciate your suggestion to seek professional advice before making this trip. It should always be the first thing when discussing activities for people who either have known physical problems, or might be vulnerable, especially if they haven't done something before.